# Updating New Created Tables From Two Tables - SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am new to sql I am using myphpadmin for my database I am trying to Update the New Created Tables named TableC From Two different Tables which are TableA and Tableb. I did combine the two tables that has common value in column and created a databse for my project. However when I updated data FROM TableA and Tableb the data in TableC is not updating. II am looking for a way where If I update Table A and Table B the TableC will also updated is it Possible in SQL? I would really appreciate any suggestions or help. Thanks in advance.

I have three tables named;

```
 TableA:

 id      Name    Section    c_status

 1a      aika    Section1   Active
 2s                         Inactive
```

===========================================

```
  TableB:

  id     PR_id     Name     Section    

  111    2s      laika     Section2   
  222    2s      Bes       Section3
```

Query used to create TableC

```
 CREATE TABLE TableC(SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Name != ''
 UNION
 SELECT TableA.id, TableB.Name, TableB.Section, TableA.c_status FROM TableA 
 INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.PR_id);
```

Output

```
TableC

id   Name   Section     c_status

1a   aika   Section1    Active
2s   laika  Section2    Inctive
2s   Bes    Section3    Inctive
```

If I updated or added data in TableA and TableB  the TableC is not updating.
I would really appreciate advice. Thank you

Comment: so, you just want to put the query result into new table?

Comment: You should create tableC with the CREATE TABLE query every time you need to update it (don’t forget to drop it first), or you should use view (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) to create tableC which automatically updates itself whenever it is called in the SELECT query calling tableC

Comment: I suspect that your third table should be a *view* not a *table*.  Then it will "update" automatically when the underlying tables change.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Exactly my point :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/51323873/9006027

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `TableC` can be automatically updated if there are any changes in `TableA` and `TableB`. However, you can try this workaround code.

```
TRUNCATE TableC;

INSERT INTO TableC(SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Name != ''
UNION
SELECT TableA.id, TableB.Name, TableB.Section, TableA.c_status FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.PR_id);
```

First, empty the `TableC` to prevent duplication. You can put the query result in the `TableC` once it is empty.

If the above query doesn't work, you can use this.

```
TRUNCATE TableC;

INSERT INTO TableC(SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Name != '');
INSERT INTO TableC(
SELECT TableA.id, TableB.Name, TableB.Section, TableA.c_status FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.PR_id);
```

Comment: thank you for the help but I am getting error right sql syntax near union

Comment: I am really grateful for your help I used the second code you suggested but I got eeror trancate column id

Comment: from the `TRUNCATE`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [View](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) for this

First you should drop the table you made

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableC;
```

Then create a view

```
CREATE VIEW TableC AS (
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Name != ''
UNION
SELECT TableA.id, TableB.Name, TableB.Section, TableA.c_status FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.PR_id
);
```

After creating the view you will always have `TableC` updated according to TableA and TableB

```
SELECT * FROM TableC
```

If you can't use View then you can always invoke the below code block before using TableC

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableC;
CREATE TABLE TableC AS (
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Name != ''
UNION
SELECT TableA.id, TableB.Name, TableB.Section, TableA.c_status FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.PR_id
);
```